# Input range slider not working in chrome? works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm currently using an input range slider to control the position of an audio track. In firefox it's working perfectly, however in Chrome The slider is stuck and doesn't move when dragged. I also have a function which updates it's position by 1 each time the currentTime of the audio changes and this may be the problem? However like I said it works perfectly on Firefox.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<audio id="music">
  <source src="media/mexico-music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
  <button id="playpausebtn" class="play"></button>
  <span id="curtimetext">00:00</span>
  <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
  <span id="durtimetext">00:00</span>
  <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var music = document.getElementById("music"),
        playpausebtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn"),
        seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider"),
        volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider"),
        curtimetext = document.getElementById("curtimetext"),
        durtimetext = document.getElementById("durtimetext"),
        seeking,
        seekto,
        curtimetext,
        durtimetext;
    // Reset slider back to 0 
    seekslider.value = 0;


    // PLAY/PAUSE AUDIO
    function playAudio() {
        if (music.paused) {
            music.play();
            playpausebtn.className = "pause";
        } else {
            music.pause();
            playpausebtn.className = "play";
        }
        music.addEventListener('ended', function () {
            playpausebtn.className = "Play";
        });
    }

    // SEEK MUSIC POSITION
    function seek(event) {
        if (seeking) {
            seekto = music.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
            music.currentTime = seekto;
        }
    }

    // VOLUME CONTROL
    function setVolume() {
        music.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
    }

    // UPDATE MUSIC TIME
    function seektimeupdate() {
        var newtime = music.currentTime * (100 / music.duration);
        seekslider.value = newtime;
        var curmins = Math.floor(music.currentTime / 60),
            cursecs = Math.floor(music.currentTime - curmins * 60),
            durmins = Math.floor(music.duration / 60),
            dursecs = Math.floor(music.duration - durmins * 60);
        // Adds 0 infront of single digit numbers
        if (cursecs < 10) { cursecs = "0" + cursecs; }
        if (dursecs < 10) { dursecs = "0" + dursecs; }
        if (curmins < 10) { curmins = "0" + curmins; }
        if (durmins < 10) { durmins = "0" + durmins; }
        curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins + ":" + cursecs;
        durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins + ":" + dursecs;
    }

    //EVENT HANDLERS
    playpausebtn.addEventListener("click", playAudio);
    seekslider.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) { seeking = true; seek(event); });
    seekslider.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) { seek(event); });
    seekslider.addEventListener("mouseup", function () { seeking = false; });
    volumeslider.addEventListener("mousemove", setVolume);
    music.addEventListener("timeupdate", seektimeupdate);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from @azs06 I managed to get this working on both Firefox and Chrome.

I removed all seekslider .addEventListener lines and only added one which has a 'change' event rather than mousedown/up etc.

The line I added is:

```
seekslider.addEventListener("change", function (event) { seeking = true; seek(event); });
```

I will update the question with the finalized code.

Comment: It would be better to include the finalized code in this answer rather than putting it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring `curtimetext,durtimetext`, also you don't need to use combination of mouseup, mousedown event, you could just use `change` event.

Working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var music = document.getElementById("music"),
        playpausebtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn"),
        seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider"),
        volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider"),
        curtimetext = document.getElementById("curtimetext"),
        durtimetext = document.getElementById("durtimetext"),
        seeking,
        seekto;

    // Reset slider back to 0 
    seekslider.value = 0;


    // PLAY/PAUSE AUDIO
    function playAudio() {
        if (music.paused) {
            music.play();
            playpausebtn.className = "pause";
        } else {
            music.pause();
            playpausebtn.className = "play";
        }
        music.addEventListener('ended', function () {
            playpausebtn.className = "Play";
        });
    }

    // SEEK MUSIC POSITION
    function seek(event) {
            seekto = music.duration * (this.value / 100);
            music.currentTime = seekto;
    }

    // VOLUME CONTROL
    function setVolume() {
        music.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
    }

    // UPDATE MUSIC TIME
    function seektimeupdate() {
        var newtime = music.currentTime * (100 / music.duration);
        seekslider.value = newtime;
        var curmins = Math.floor(music.currentTime / 60),
            cursecs = Math.floor(music.currentTime - curmins * 60),
            durmins = Math.floor(music.duration / 60),
            dursecs = Math.floor(music.duration - durmins * 60);
        // Adds 0 infront of single digit numbers
        if (cursecs < 10) { cursecs = "0" + cursecs; }
        if (dursecs < 10) { dursecs = "0" + dursecs; }
        if (curmins < 10) { curmins = "0" + curmins; }
        if (durmins < 10) { durmins = "0" + durmins; }
        curtimetext.innerHTML = curmins + ":" + cursecs;
        durtimetext.innerHTML = durmins + ":" + dursecs;
    }

    //EVENT HANDLERS
    playpausebtn.addEventListener("click", playAudio);
    seekslider.addEventListener("change", seek);
 
    volumeslider.addEventListener("mousemove", setVolume);
    music.addEventListener("timeupdate", seektimeupdate);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="music">
  <source src="//mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2587/AudioTest%20(1).ogg" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
  <button id="playpausebtn" class="play">
   play
  </button>
  <span id="curtimetext">00:00</span>
  <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
  <span id="durtimetext">00:00</span>
  <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Learn more about change event from mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change